# Limit a number and rotate it, within a range

Tags: ruby, range, rotation

Is there a more Ruby-ish and cleaner way to get a number to operate within a range. If it hits the upper bound, the next number should be 1 again. Often seen in algorythms that e.g. force month 16 and 28 to be April (16-12=4).

The case: I have twelve images and N questions. Each question gets the next image, if all images are "used", it should re-start at image 1.

```
def image_rotation(number) {
   uplim = 12

   return number if number <= uplim
   return image_rotation(number - uplim) if number > uplim
}

questions.each_with_index do |q,i|
  img = File::join("images", "image-#{image_rotation(i+1)}.jpg")
end
```

Note: I am not familiar with the terminology of this (kind of) problem, so searching stackoverflow did not give me any results or hints; but I cannot believe this question is not a duplicate, yet. Please point me to a keyword, answer/duplicate or feel free to answer it :)

And Bonuspoints for a one-liner. I need this in an ERB-file, so if I can keep the code clean, clear and simple, then I prefer to have it solved there, entirely.

Comment: Is there other code in `image_rotation` to make calling itself necessary? Or is what you've posted the actual, whole method?

Comment: No. The reason I call `image_rotation` itself, is to turn e.g. 26 into 2, in two rounds.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [modulo (`%`)](http://ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Fixnum.html#method-i-25):

```
def image_rotation(number) do
   upper_limit = 12
   number % upper_limit
end

image_rotation(12) #=> 12
image_rotation(13) #=> 1
```

If that's all your method does, though, you could just do:

```
i % 12
```

Answer (score 1):

The keyword is modulo; the ruby method is [modulo](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Fixnum.html#method-i-modulo), its shorthand equivalent is `%`

```
16 % 12 #=> 4
28 % 12 #=> 4
```

Comment: @Andrew Marshall Thanks ! English not being my first language I had to  google when to use which - but now I know. I hope to remember its use...